# Setting the return value in vba function invokes the function itself

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following function to get unique values in the array. However in the second last line, UniqueArray(i) = TempArray(i), it invokes the function itself again instead of assigning the array value.
Thanks for any help.

```
Function UniqueArray(MyArray) As Variant

Dim TempArray As Variant
ReDim TempArray(0)
TempArray(0) = MyArray(LBound(MyArray))
For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
      If Not IsInArray(TempArray, MyArray(i)) Then
            ReDim Preserve TempArray(UBound(TempArray) + 1)
            TempArray(UBound(TempArray)) = MyArray(i)
      End If
Next i

ReDim MyArray(UBound(TempArray))
For i = LBound(TempArray) To UBound(TempArray)
    UniqueArray(i) = TempArray(i)
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Get rid of the loop and use `UniqueArray = TempArray` to return the array.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the TempArray array back as a whole. You shouldn't need to rely on 'helper' functions to determine uniqueness as an Excel.Application has multiple options.

```
Sub main()
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5)

    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")    '1,2,2,3,4,5,5

    arr = UniqueArray(arr)

    Debug.Print Join(arr, ",")    '1,2,3,4,5

End Sub

Function UniqueArray(MyArray) As Variant

    Dim i As Long, TempArray As Variant

    ReDim TempArray(0)
    TempArray(0) = MyArray(LBound(MyArray))

    For i = LBound(MyArray) + 1 To UBound(MyArray)
          If IsError(Application.Match(MyArray(i), TempArray, 0)) Then
                ReDim Preserve TempArray(UBound(TempArray) + 1)
                TempArray(UBound(TempArray)) = MyArray(i)
          End If
    Next i

    UniqueArray = TempArray

End Function
```

If the function is to be used outside of Excel, then you will likely want to retain the IsInArray companion function.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you would need to redim *UniqueArray* not *MyArray* since *MyArray* is the input for the function.  Since you have not declared it as an array yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am afraid it says redim is invalid. If you do the dim within the function you get the error multiple declaration.